# Cannot load class in Mini2 framework app

Tags: php

I am creating a PHP application using the Mini2 framework.

https://github.com/panique/mini2

This is a very barebone MVC framework. In my index.php file I have to declare various routes, models, etc.

I am sharing the snippet where I declare the models.

```
$model = new \Mini\Model\Model($app->config('database'));
$usermodel = new \Mini\Model\User\userModel($app->config('database'));
```

In my project root directory ... there are these files

/Mini/Model/Model.php

/Mini/Model/userModel.php

Here is what my Model.php looks like

```
<?php

namespace Mini\Model;

use PDO;

class Model
{
    private $db;

    function __construct($config)
    {
        // PDO db connection statement preparation
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $config['db_host'] . ';dbname='    . $config['db_name'] . ';port=' . $config['db_port'];

        // note the PDO::FETCH_OBJ, returning object ($result->id) instead of array ($result["id"])
        // @see http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.construct.php
        $options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

        // create new PDO db connection
        $this->db = new PDO($dsn, $config['db_user'], $config['db_pass'], $options);
    }

}
```

Here is what my userModel.php looks like

```
<? php


namespace Mini\Model\User;


use PDO;


class userModel
{
    /private $db;


    function __construct($config)
    {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host='. $config['db_host']. ';dbname='. $config['db_name']. ';port='. $config['db_port'];
        $options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
        $this->db = new PDO($dsn, $config['db_user'], $config['db_pass'], $options);
    }
}
```

When I run my web app, I get this error.

[image]

Both my model files are being used and declared in the same way, but only one can be accessed. Only Model.php can be accessed.

I checked the internal files of Mini2 framework and could not find any file where require or include statement is used to pre load the files. I am at a loss now.

Following Michael's suggesstion, I moved the userModel file into a new folder called User inside model.

/Mini/Model/User/userModel.php

Then I get this error

[image]

The php server is just dumping a part of the file contents.

Comment: Your filepath for userModel.php is wrong. It should be in a sub-dir of `Model` called `User` like so: `/Mini/Model/User/userModel.php`

Comment: Delete space in `<? php` in your UserModel.php

Answer (score 0):

Several things here:

1. /Mini/Model/userModel.php should be /Mini/Model/UserModel.php
2. **namespace Mini\Model\User;** should be **namespace Mini\Model;**
3. **class userModel {** should be **class UserModel {**
4. Remove the slash before **private $db**
5. Line 72 in your index.php should be like **$user = new \Mini\Model\UserModel($config)**
6. You must make sure that you are using a autoloader. If you could access Mini\Model\Model from index.php then you probably are.